# tensorflow lite label_image and benchmark tool with default cmake built under Ubuntu results weird behaviour

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, benchmarking, tflite

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with gcc 9.4.0.
I tried the build the tensorflow lite label_image and benchmark tool using the standard CMake procedure.
I followed the office instruction [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/guide/build_cmake.md) and tried on both tensorflow lite 2.9.3 and 2.13.0 and tested using the model [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_and_labels.zip).

In particular, I built the tensorflow lite with command:
`cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite`
then, built the label_image example and benchmark tool:

```
cmake --build . -j -t benchmark_model
cmake --build . -j -t label_image
```

I used the following code to test:

```
# for benchmark, with xnnpack
benchmark_model --graph=./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite --use_xnnpack=true
# for benchmark, no xnnpack
benchmark_model --graph=./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite --use_xnnpack=false
# label_image, with xnnpack
label_image -m ./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite -i ./grace_hopper.bmp  -l labels.txt -x 1
# label_image, no xnnpack
label_image -m ./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite -i ./grace_hopper.bmp  -l labels.txt -x 0
```

The **1st issue** is that the xnnpack is not working.
Here is the log using the xnnpack:

```
STARTING!
Log parameter values verbosely: [0]
Graph: [./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite]
Use xnnpack: [1]
Loaded model ./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
XNNPACK delegate created.
Though XNNPACK delegate is explicitly applied, the model graph will not be executed by the delegate.
```

And the inferencing time is not different whether using xnnpack or not.

The **2nd issue** is that benchmark tool shows a unreasonably high DepthwiseConv2D op duration.
I used the following command to benchmark ops:

```
benchmark_model --graph=./mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite --enable_op_profiling=true
```

and output:

```
============================== Summary by node type ==============================
                 [Node type]      [count]     [avg ms]      [avg %]     [cdf %]   [mem KB]  [times called]
                     CONV_2D           15       **38.265**      58.415%     58.415%      0.000         15
           DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D           13       **27.230**      41.569%     99.985%      0.000         13
             AVERAGE_POOL_2D            1        0.007       0.011%     99.995%      0.000          1
                     SOFTMAX            1        0.003       0.005%    100.000%      0.000          1
                     RESHAPE            1        0.000       0.000%    100.000%      0.000          1
```

The 13 x DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D should consume MUCH less than 15 x CONV_2D.

The above problem was observed using **CMake** procedure with tflite 2.9.3, and 2.13.0.
Using **bazel**, instead, I see the problems only with tflite 2.9.3. The bazel build for 2.13.0 seems to produce correct results.

Has anybody tried to build and test tflite xnnpack & benchmark tool using CMake ?

Many thanks in advance !